# Show the sequence $a_n$ with $a_1 = 10$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}a_n+2$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show the sequence $a_n$ with $a_1 = 10$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}a_n+2$ is convergent

I'm not sure how to solve this. I've tried a couple different things.

1. I believe the sequence is bounded below by 2 as $a_n \ge 0$ (not sure how to prove this)? If I could should the sequence is decreasing then I would have convergence (again not sure how to prove this. I tried $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ but did not progress anywhere).
2. Maybe I could prove this sequence is Cauchy and thus converges? (not sure how to do this either).

Thanks.

Comment: It's easy to show that $a_n > 0$ or that $a_n > 2$ by induction - but no, $2$ is not the limit. If the sequence does have a limit $L$, then intuitively for really large $n$ we have $a_{n+1} \approx L$ and $a_n \approx L$, so $L \approx \frac{1}{2} L + 2$...

Comment: I can see that L = 4 but I'm not sure how I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach:

This approach is allowable under the assumption that the problem asks only that convergence be demonstrated, rather than actually having to calculate what the limit is.

It is sufficient to show that :

- The sequence is bounded below.
- The sequence is strictly decreasing.

$a_1 > 0.$ 
Suppose that $a_n > 0.$ 
Then $(1/2)a_n > 0$ and $2 > 0$. 
Therefore, $a_{n+1} = (1/2)a_n + 2 > 0$. 
Therefore, the sequence is bounded below.

$a_1 > 4$. 
Suppose that $a_n > 4$. 
Then $a_{n+1} = (1/2)a_n + 2 < (1/2)a_n + (1/2)a_n = a_n$. 
Further, $a_{n+1} = (1/2)a_n + 2  > 2 + 2 = 4.$ 
Therefore, if $a_n > 4$ then you have that:

- $a_{n+1} < a_n.$
- $a_{n+1} > 4.$

Therefore, the sequence is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Hey, I'm slightly confused about the last part of the second induction. Why do we need to specify 'Therefore, if an>4 then you have that:'. Have we not proved the two statements following this for all $a_n$, as we know $a_1 = 10 > 4$?

Comment: @Joeyboy To show that the sequence is strictly decreasing, it is **not sufficient** to show that if $a_n > 4$ then $a_{n+1} < a_n$.  You must also show that if $a_n > 4$ then $a_{n+1} > 4.$  For example, take the **hypothetical** situation where $a_n = 5$ and (somehow) $a_{n+1} = 3.$  Because $a_n > 4$, you can then conclude that $a_{n+1} < a_n$.  However, with $a_{n+1}~$ hypothetically $< 4$, you can **not** then conclude that $a_{n+2} < a_{n+1}$.  This is because the inference that the sequence is strictly decreasing **critically depends** on each individual element being $> 4$.

Answer (score 3):

$a_{n+1}-4=(a_n-4)/2$,
so $a_n-4=(a_1-4)/2^{n-1}$ follows by induction.

Answer (score 2):

Use induction to prove the statement $4 \leqslant a_{n+1} \leqslant a_n$ for every index $n$, which of course means the sequence is monotone and bounded, and thus convergent to some limit $L$. The base case is trivial to check. And assuming the statement true for $n$, you have
$$4 = \frac{1}{2}(4) + \frac{1}{2}(4) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}(a_{n+1}) + \frac{1}{2}(4) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} (a_{n+1}) + \frac{1}{2} (a_{n+1}) = a_{n+1},$$
so upon realizing the middle expression is equal to $a_{n+2}$ you can complete the inductive step.

Of course, to confirm $L = 4$ note the limit must satisfy $\frac{1}{2}L + 2 = L$.

Comment: +1: I guess that there is no quality control on upvoting of answers.  I see no rational way of concluding that my answer is better than yours.

Answer (score 1):

We can just solve the recurrence relation : $2a_{n+1} - a_{n} - 4 = 0$.

Without the $-4$, the relation becomes a homogeneous recurrence relation. Therefore the general solution and particular solution of each recurrence relations are :

$$a_{n}^{*} = \frac{A}{2^{n}},\:\:\:a_{n}^{**} = p = 4.$$

where $A$ is a constant. Therefore,

$$a_{n} = a_{n}^{*} + a_{n}^{**} = \frac{A}{2^{n}} + 4 = \frac{12}{2^{n}} + 4.$$

I would still prefer using @Yuval Peres' method, since it is a simple relation. However this can also be solved with general methods for non-homogeneous recurrence relations.